# Ansible - Read file and register variable

Tags: ansible

I have a file with the following content:

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=xxxxxxx

AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=yyyyyy

AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=zzzzzzzz

How do I read this file, split the line based on "=" and set the values of the variables (AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, AWS_SESSION_TOKEN)  so that I can use these variables in the script for later use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Q: *How do I read this file, split the line based on "=" and set the values of the variables?*

A: Use [ini](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup/ini.html#ini-read-data-from-a-ini-file) lookup plugin. For example the tasks below

```
- set_fact:
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: "{{ lookup('ini', 'AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID type=properties file=conf.ini') }}"
- debug:
    var: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
```

give

```
"AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID": "xxxxxxx"
```

It is possible to use a list of variables. For example the play below

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    my_vars_keys: [AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, AWS_SESSION_TOKEN]
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        my_vars: "{{ my_vars|default({})|
                     combine({item:
                              lookup('ini',
                                      item ~ ' type=properties file=conf.ini')})
                                      }}"
      loop: "{{ my_vars_keys }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ my_vars[item] }}"
      loop: "{{ my_vars_keys }}"
```

gives

```
ok: [localhost] => (item=AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID) => {
    "msg": "xxxxxxx"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY) => {
    "msg": "yyyyyy"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=AWS_SESSION_TOKEN) => {
    "msg": "zzzzzzzz"
}
```

---

> Q: *How do I make sure that above set_fact runs on the hosts and not on the ansible tower?*

A: The set_fact uses [Lookup Plugins](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup.html#lookup-plugins). Quoting

> Like all templating, these plugins are evaluated on the Ansible control machine, not on the target/remote.

Comment: I am runnign the script from ansible tower targeting to hosts:

When using something like: 
WS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: "{{ lookup('ini', 'access_key type=properties file=/tmp/token') }}"

I am getting unable to find the file - /tmp/token'
How do I make sure that above set_fact runs on the hosts and not on the ansible tower.

Comment: Lookup plugins are evaluated on the Ansible control machine. It is possible to [fetch](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/fetch_module.html#fetch-fetch-files-from-remote-nodes) such a file from the remote host.